# Test of two variance ratios being equal

Tags: time-series, statistics

Assume I have two integrated times-series A and B. I take log differences, that are stationary, and I compute the variance ratios for both time-series for several horizons k=2,...,n.

Now I want to test whether the variance ratio with horizon, say k, for the time-series A is equal to the corresponding variance ratio for the time-series B.

I know that $\sqrt(N)(VR(k)-1)$ is asymptotically normal with asymptotic variance that can be computed under either homoscedasticity or heteroscedasticity.

My goal is the asymptotic distribution of $\sqrt(N)(VR_A(k) - VR_B(k))$. How do I derive it? Any reference or code?